# Can't deserialize Rest Assured response when target includes an enumeration

Tags: java, deserialization, fasterxml

I'm using Rest Assured in my integration tests and I'm getting an exception when deserializing response bodies into their respective entity when the entity include an enumeration that has a custom deserializer.  I'm guessing Rest Assured is not aware of, not triggering or is somehow blocking the custom deserializer?

Here's the exception I'm getting:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "displayName" (class jafwatt.kompreno.model.Project), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "workspaceId", "estimateType", "projectId", "phases", "projectName"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"projectId":9,"workspaceId":74,"projectName":"Test Project 1dea0d3e-4bba-4cc2-ace3-77dede4990d5","phases":[],"estimateType":{"name":"DAY","displayName":"Days","id":1}}"; line: 1, column: 155] (through reference chain: jafwatt.kompreno.model.Project["displayName"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3042)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper$readValue$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.mapping.JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.groovy:47)
    at io.restassured.path.json.mapping.JsonPathObjectDeserializer$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.deserialize(Jackson2Mapper.groovy:58)
    at io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper$deserialize$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.parseWithJackson2(ObjectMapping.groovy:204)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$parseWithJackson2$1.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.deserialize(ObjectMapping.groovy:57)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$deserialize$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:220)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:166)
    at jafwatt.kompreno.tests.steps.APISteps.processAPIResponse(APISteps.java:155)
    at jafwatt.kompreno.tests.steps.APISteps.doAPIRequest(APISteps.java:50)
    at ✽.a POST request is made to the project API(C:/code/kompreno/tests/src/test/resources/features/api/plan.feature:8)
```

Here's how I'm triggering the deserialization@

```
private void processAPIResponse(final ExtractableResponse response) {
    Object entity = response.body().as(Project.class);
}
```

Here's the target entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Project {

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private WorkPackageEstimateType estimateType = WorkPackageEstimateType.DAY;

    public WorkPackageEstimateType getEstimateType() {
        return estimateType;
    }

    public void setEstimateType(WorkPackageEstimateType estimateType) {
        this.estimateType = estimateType;
    }
}
```

Here's the enum:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize(using = WorkPackageEstimateTypeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = WorkPackageEstimateTypeDeserializer.class)
public enum WorkPackageEstimateType {
    HOUR("Hours"),
    DAY("Days"),
    WEEK("Weeks"),
    STORY_POINT("Story Points"),
    ITERATION("Iterations");

    private String displayName;

    WorkPackageEstimateType(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return ordinal();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return toString();
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

And here's the custom deserializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WorkPackageEstimateTypeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<WorkPackageEstimateType> {

    public WorkPackageEstimateTypeDeserializer() {
        super(WorkPackageEstimateType.class);
    }

    public WorkPackageEstimateTypeDeserializer(Class<WorkPackageEstimateType> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public WorkPackageEstimateType deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        WorkPackageEstimateType value = null;
        JsonToken currentToken = null;
        while ((currentToken = parser.nextValue()) != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentName().equals("name")) {
                value = WorkPackageEstimateType.valueOf(parser.getText());
                break;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```